# SAPUI5: Get row by key from JSON Model

Tags: sapui5

I have the following model. 
Now I want to select one row in a function with a specific condition.

model.json

```
{
    "collection": [
        {
        "nr": "99990655",
        "machine": "Test A"
        },
        {
        "nr": "123435546",
        "machine": "Test B"
        }
        ]
}
```

I successfully get the first row with the following command:
`this.getView().getModel("machinemodel").getProperty("/collection/0")`

Now I want the row where nr is '123435546'.

`this.getView().getModel("machinemodel").getProperty("/collection(nr='123435546')")` is not working.

Comment: If your collection is an entity set then each entity should have a key. Are you sure this is an OData model?

Comment: This is a JSON-Model. I use it for testing. In productivity I changed the model to an ODATA-Interface from a SAP Gateway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal way is to implement a filter for this job. But if you need it in your javascript code you have to search for the index of the number. For example:

```
var collection = this.getView().getModel("machinemodel").getData().collection
var index = $.inArray('123435546', $.map(collection, function(n){
    return n.nr
}
this.getView().getModel("machinemodel").getProperty("/collection/"+index )
```